# Intermittent Slow SQLite Inserts

Tags: web-server, sqlite

Using a test script with test data, the average time to complete an insert, with SQLite3, is about 10ms.

But about 3% of the time I do an insert it takes between 1 and 3 seconds to complete.

I'm running a fairly recent build of Raspbian from a few months ago and SQLite 3.8.4.

The process doing the inserts jumps from about 5% CPU usage to 10% when the slow inserts happen, but otherwise the CPU usage is normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: What class is your SD card? I suspect your issue might be I/O.

Comment: It's a class 10 SD card.

Comment: Try storing the db in a RAM filesystem instead of the SD-card and run the test again. Any difference?

Comment: Yeah, I just thought of doing that earlier. It fixes the issue, so now I at least know that it's a problem with writing to the SD card itself. I'm going to try a few different SD cards to see if it's any different.